# Plone 4: Passing arguments to view class (BrowserView)

Tags: python, plone

I have been following [this URL](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-a-custom-template-for-a-plone-content-type) to help me create template views using BrowserView. So far, it works OK and I am able to create a template with a view class.

What I need to know is whether it is possible to pass arguments to methods inside the view class i.e.

```
from Products.Five import BrowserView

class Html(BrowserView):
    def still_dreaming(self):
        msg = "Some people are still dreaming"
        return msg
```

I need to add an extra argument to the still_dreaming function and process it inside the function like this:

```
def still_dreaming(self, some_arg):
        msg = some_arg + " Some people are still dreaming"
        return msg
```

Then I need to call the function and pass an argument to it from my template. Something like this:

```
<p tal:content="view/still_dreaming(item/publication_date)"></p>
```

Unfortunately, I do not know the correct way of passing arguments to the method. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
`item/publication_date` is just some variable and could be anything. It has just been defined previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
  <p tal:content="python:view.still_dreaming(item.publication_date)" />
```

You can use TAL traversing syntax (default), Python syntax or String syntax in TAL expressions.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functionality/expressions.html

Comment: Got the same.
But I read somewhere on the internet that making "python:" in views are bad...
So sometimes, I am a little bit confused.

Comment: python: is bad in a sense that in past there were no view classes and all code was put inside in the templates, making it a mess of HTML and one liner pythons

Comment: Now you can put complex Python loops and functions in real .py file and View class

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thanks. This managed to work for me and I will leave it that way for now. Much obliged.

Comment: Alternative put loop into View class and make look return a list of dicts (e.g. containing item/publication_data) as an item. Then you use tal:repeat to iterate over this list. This way you can avoid python: in TAL and have little bit smarter and faster loop.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thanks. I didn't think of that. Still new into Python/Plone.